# Gantry 5 Particle, change field type to accept HTML

Tags: twig, particles

I'm using Gantry 5 with the Supra theme, and want to change the "Panel slider" particle's description field to accept and render HTML code.

I tried to change the Twig config by adding the `|raw` parameter, in an override file, but it still does not render the HTML.

What I'm doing wrong here?
I changed the `panelslider.html.twig` here: `{{ item.description|raw }}`
I also tried it with `|e` and `|html`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since my Gantry was in Production mode, I just needed to clear the cache in Gantry > Extras > Clear Cache.